# problem using Uniprot SPARQL endpoint and CONSTRUCT

Tags: sparql, rdflib, construct, sparqlwrapper

From SPARQLwrapper I can successfully query and return results using SPARQL select. When I try to use the CONSTRUCT example from the website I get and error "`ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0`"

I've tested my code with a dbpedia example

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX sdo: <https://schema.org/>

    CONSTRUCT {
      ?lang a sdo:Language ;
      sdo:alternateName ?iso6391Code .
    }
    WHERE {
      ?lang a dbo:Language ;
      dbo:iso6391Code ?iso6391Code .
      FILTER (STRLEN(?iso6391Code)=2) # to filter out non-valid values
    }
    LIMIT 3
""")

results = sparql.queryAndConvert()

print("results")
print(results.serialize())
print("- - - - - - - - -")
```

the DBpedia example works fine.But, when trying the same on Uniprot like this ...

```
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://sparql.uniprot.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
PREFIX taxon: <http://purl.uniprot.org/taxonomy/>
PREFIX up: <http://purl.uniprot.org/core/>
CONSTRUCT
{
    ?protein a up:HumanProtein .
}
WHERE
{
    ?protein a up:Protein .
    ?protein up:organism taxon:9606 .
}
""")

results = sparql.queryAndConvert()
```

I get this error

> "ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0"

Comment: you can try to call `sparql.setOnlyConneg(True)` to avoid adding weird legacy params to the URL

Comment: thanks! using sparql.setOnlyConneg(True) fixed the problem. What does it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try going directly to https://sparql.uniprot.org as this might be the issue.

Comment: I get the same issue using  https://sparql.uniprot.org.